# BeautifulSoup and Python scraping around a js tag, maybe?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to get multiple headlines, links and dates. Only getting the first one. Not sure why BS4 won't fetch all the items...Is it a javascript problem?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen

html = urlopen("http://www.fiercepharma.com/news")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read().decode('utf-8'),"lxml")
main_div = soup.select_one("div#content")
div_sub = main_div.select("div.region.region-content")

for d in div_sub:
    date = d.time.get_text()
    headline = d.h2.a.get_text()
    url = d.a["href"]
    print headline, url, date
```

Comment: thats cos souping div.region.region-content gives you the whole data as one element. Let me try a code and send you.

Comment: replace your `div_sub`  part with `div_sub = main_div.select(".card.horizontal.views-row")` and it is working fine.

Comment: thank you - could you tell me why it was hanging ont the leading 'div' in 'div.card.horizontal.views-row'? ... I had tried using that tag with the div on the the front.

Comment: as far as the css selectors are concerned i dont see any difference between `div.card.horizontal.views-row` or `.card.horizontal.views-row`. Both should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `div.card.horizontal.views-row` and `.card.horizontal.views-row` should work @citra_amarillo. I ran this and it work bothways

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen


html = urlopen("http://www.fiercepharma.com/news")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read().decode('utf-8'),"lxml")
main_div = soup.select_one("div#content")
div_sub = main_div.select(".card.horizontal.views-row") 
#div_sub = main_div.select("div.card.horizontal.views-row")

for d in div_sub:
    date = d.time.get_text()
    headline = d.h2.a.get_text()
    url = d.a["href"]
    print headline, url, date
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using the following to capture all the articles that contain links, authors, posting dates on the main page. You could store this in a dictionary, or store it in a pandas dataframe for easy manipulation.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

baseurl = 'http://www.fiercepharma.com'
response = requests.get(baseurl)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

cdict = {}

for group in soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'card horizontal views-row'}):
    try:
        title = group.find('h2', {'class' : 'field-content list-title'}).text
        link = baseurl + group.find('h2', {'class' : 'field-content list-title'}).find('a', href=True)['href']
        author = group.find('span', {'class' : 'field-content'}).find('a').text
        time = group.find('span', {'class' : 'field-content'}).find('time').text
        content = group.find('p', {'class' : 'field-content card-text'}).text
        cdict[link] = {'title' : title, 'author' : author, 'time' : time, 'content' : content}
    except AttributeError as e:
        print('[-] Unable to parse {}'.format(e))

print(cdict)
#{'http://www.fiercepharma.com/manufacturing/lonza-bulks-up-5-5b-deal-for-capsugel': {'author': u'Eric Palmer',
#  'content': u'Swiss CDMO Lonza has pulled the trigger on a $5.5 billion deal to acquire the U.S.-based contract capsule and drug producer Capsugel to create another sizable\u2026',
#  'time': u'Dec 15, 2016 8:45am',
# 'title': u'Lonza bulks up with $5.5B deal for Capsugel'},
```